# KeyError: when making new column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am working on a dataset and when I try to create a new column after find the difference I get the **KeyError: 'filtered'**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'col2': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(8,8))

df['col2'].diff().plot(ax=ax[0])

cutoff = 3
df['filtered'] = df.loc[df['col2'].diff().abs() > cutoff]
df.plot(ax=ax[1])
```

I used to create new column like this `(df['filtered'] = some operation)`, but it gives `KeyError: 'filtered'` in this situation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to create `filtered` with bool type?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to assign `filtered` to, but you can use `df.assign(filtered = <something_here>)`

Comment: `df.loc[df['col2'].diff().abs() > cutoff]` returns a dataframe with two columns. You are trying to assign it to a new column named `filtered`. Can't do it

Comment: The way you are using filtered in this case is incorrect. For example, if it is less than the cuttoff what should the column be equal to? It seems like you are trying to decide if you want a new dataframe or a boolean column, but got stuck in between.

Comment: Are you trying to make `filtered` equal to `[np.nan, np.nan, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0, 17.0, 19.0]`? Or do you just want filtered to be equal to `col2` if the difference is greater than 3 between the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the second-to-last line with:

```
df['filtered'] = df.loc[df['col2'].diff().abs() > cutoff, 'col2']
```

assuming that you want to get a filtered version of 'col2'. As @RafaelC mentioned, the current .loc[] operation you have returns all the columns (2 in this case) for which the row filter applies hence the error.